# Can only add two values in prepared statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, prepared-statement

I'm very new to PHP and trying to create basic webservice. 
Here is the code

```
 $type_general = $_GET["type_general"];
        $name = $_GET["name"];
        $firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
        $institution = $_GET["institution"];
        $institution_name = $_GET["institution_name"];
        $street_nr = $_GET["street_nr"];
        $city_postal = $_GET["city_postal"];
        $email = $_GET["email"];
        $telephone = $_GET["telephone"];
        $name_firstname_pneumoloog = $_GET["name_firstname_pneumoloog"];
        $riziv_pneumoloog = $_GET["riziv_pneumoloog"];
        $riziv = $_GET["riziv"];
        $type_specialist = $_GET["type_specialist"];

        // Add tracking of redemption
       // $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Registration (id,type_general,name,firstname,institution,institution_name,street_nr,city_postal,email,telephone,name_firstname_pneumoloog,riziv_pneumoloog,type_specialist,riziv) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
      //  $stmt->bind_param("is",NULL, $type_general, $name,$firstname,$institution,$institution_name,$street_nr,$city_postal,$email,$telephone,$name_firstname_pneumoloog,$riziv_pneumoloog,$type_specialist,$riziv);

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Registration (type_general,name) VALUES (?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("is",$type_general,$name);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $this->db->commit();
```

I have the following problems:

- For the parameter `type_general` it always put 0 in my DB
- When I try to add all the parameters it doesn't insert anything in my DB

Can anybody please help me with this?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code looks like mysqli, you need the first parameter of `bind_param()` to [specify the types](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) of the variables.

So:

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Registration (type_general,name) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("is",$type_general,$name);
```

assumes that the first parameter is an integer. If it is not - if it is a string - you would need:

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Registration (type_general,name) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$type_general,$name);
```

And to insert all values:

```
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Registration (type_general,name,firstname,institution,institution_name,street_nr,city_postal,email,telephone,name_firstname_pneumoloog,riziv_pneumoloog,type_specialist,riziv) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssss",$type_general,$name,$firstname,$institution,$institution_name,$street_nr,$city_postal,$email,$telephone,$name_firstname_pneumoloog,$riziv_pneumoloog,$type_specialist,$riziv);
```

assuming that all variables are supposed to be strings...

Answer (score 1):

With `$stmt->bind_param` you only bind on alias to one parameter, which means that you need to call the function twice, e.g.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Registration (type_general,name) VALUES (:t,:n)");
$stmt->bind_param(":t",$type_general);
$stmt->bind_param(":n",$name);
```

Comment: You are assuming PDO but the OP's code looks more like mysqli where you bind all your parameters in one `bind_param()` call.